# Error: 'sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory', while it does exists

Tags: r, path, filepath

When I run

```
    R CMD INSTALL CopulaModule
```

in the correct folder I get the following error

```
#sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

But this specific location does exists. What can be the problem? I installed `RTools` corresponding to my version of `R` (3.5.0).